# Resnet autoencoder in keras I/0 issues

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I am trying to code a deep auto encoder in keras. My image shape is (4575,32,32,3) and targets are (4575,1)

Here's the function

```
def build_deep_autoencoder(img_shape, code_size):
    
    H,W,C = img_shape
    
    # encoder
    encoder = Sequential()

    encoder.add(L.InputLayer(img_shape))
    encoder.add(ResNet50(include_top=False,pooling='avg'))
    encoder.add(Flatten())
    encoder.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    encoder.add(Dropout(0.5))
    encoder.add(BatchNormalization())
    encoder.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    encoder.add(Dropout(0.5))
    encoder.add(BatchNormalization())
    encoder.add(Dense(code_size))

    # decoder
    decoder = Sequential()
    decoder.add(L.InputLayer((code_size,)))
    encoder.add(Flatten())
    decoder.add(Dense(2*2*256))
    decoder.add(Reshape((2, 2, 256)))
    decoder.add(Conv2DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, activation='elu', padding='same'))
    decoder.add(Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, activation='elu', padding='same'))
    decoder.add(Conv2DTranspose(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, activation='elu', padding='same'))
    decoder.add(Conv2DTranspose(filters=3, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, activation=None, padding='same'))
    
    return encoder, decoder

        encoder,decoder = build_deep_autoencoder(img_shape,code_size=2)

        inp = L.Input(img_shape)
        code = encoder(inp)
        reconstruction = decoder(code)

        autoencoder = tensorflow.keras.models.Model(inp,reconstruction)

        encoder.summary()


        autoencoder.compile('nadam','mse')
        autoencoder.fit(x=X,y=y,epochs=10)
```

I am getting an error:

> InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [31,32,32,3] vs. [31,1]
> [[{{node            training_18/Nadam/gradients/loss_12/sequential_28_loss/MeanSquaredError/sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]]

I am using tensorflow.python.keras

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add a standalone code to reproduce this error.

Comment: Notice that you're adding to the `encoder` under the `decoder` code part.

Comment: Get rid of the flatten layer. That should do the job. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56912176/target-array-shape-different-to-expected-output-using-tensorflow